# gtsummary tbl_regression for a case-cohort model from survival::cch in R

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to run a case-cohort model using the `survival::cch` function and then print the model coefficients and confidence intervals using `gtsummary::tbl_regression()`. When trying to summarize the model, `tbl_regression()` indicates that the model tidying has failed, though tidying outside of `tbl_regression` is successful. Is there a way to summarize the case-cohort model using `gtsummary`?

```
library(survival)
library(gtsummary)

# case-cohort model using the survival::cch function
# example from survival::cch()

## The complete Wilms Tumor Data 
## (Breslow and Chatterjee, Applied Statistics, 1999)
## subcohort selected by simple random sampling.
##

subcoh <- nwtco$in.subcohort
selccoh <- with(nwtco, rel==1|subcoh==1)
ccoh.data <- nwtco[selccoh,]
ccoh.data$subcohort <- subcoh[selccoh]
## central-lab histology 
ccoh.data$histol <- factor(ccoh.data$histol,labels=c("FH","UH"))
## tumour stage
ccoh.data$stage <- factor(ccoh.data$stage,labels=c("I","II","III","IV"))
ccoh.data$age <- ccoh.data$age/12 # Age in years

##
## Standard case-cohort analysis: simple random subcohort 
##

fit.ccP <- cch(Surv(edrel, rel) ~ stage + histol + age, data =ccoh.data,
               subcoh = ~subcohort, id=~seqno, cohort.size=4028)


fit.ccP


# tidy model output: success
broom::tidy(fit.ccP)

# try to put model into tbl_regression 
# ! `broom::tidy()` failed to tidy the model.
# v `tidy_parameters()` used instead.
# i Add `tidy_fun = broom.helpers::tidy_parameters` to quiet these messages.
# Error in if (result$label %in% c("Beta", "exp(Beta)")) { : 
#     argument is of length zero
#   In addition: Warning messages:
#     1: The `exponentiate` argument is not supported in the `tidy()` method for `cch` objects and will be ignored. 
#   2: Some model terms could not be found in model data.
#   You probably need to load the data into the environment. 
tbl_regression(fit.ccP)
```

Comment: Please update your post with a minimal reproducible example (something we can all run on our machines as well).

Comment: The nwtco dataset should load with the survival package. Please let me know if you need more info!

Comment: Ahh, thank you! The `cch()` model is currently not supported. If you file an issue at https://github.com/larmarange/broom.helpers/issues and request support and include this example, it looks like something that can be supported. Replace the `tbl_regression()` call with `broom.helpers::tidy_plus_plus()` when you file the issue. Here's a list of supported model types: https://larmarange.github.io/broom.helpers/articles/tidy.html#supported-models